# Endless while loop in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am currently writing a simple crawler in python2.7 using urllib2. Here is the downloader class.

```
class Downloader:
    def __init__(self, limit = 3):
        self.limit = limit

    def downloadGet(self, url):
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        retry = 0
        succ = False
        page = None

        while retry < self.limit:
            print "Retry: " + str(retry) + " Limit:" + str(self.limit)
            try:
                response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
                page = response.read()
                succ = True
                break
            except:
                retry += 1

        return succ, page
```

Every url will be tried for three times. Multi-threading is also used, and the thread code is as follows:

```
class DownloadThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self, requestGet, limit):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.requestGet = requestGet
        self.downloader = Downloader(limit)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            url = self.requestGet()
            if url == None:
                break

            ret = self.download(url)
            print ret

    def download(self, url):
        # some other staff
        succ, flv = self.downloader.downloadGet(url)
        return succ
```

However, during experiments, in which threads' number is set to 5, the downloader does not stop after trying for 3 times. The output shows even "Retry: 4280 Limit:3" for some thread. It seems the while condition is ignored.

Any help and suggestion is firmly welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the code that create `DownloadThread` instance?

Comment: Is it possible you are reading the limit from the command line without converting it to an int first? If limit is actually "3" and not the integer 3, you would get behavior like this, e.g., `4280 < "3"` is `True`.

Comment: @Constantine Thanks! That's where the trick lies. I do forget to do the converting after reading the "limit" parameter from file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible cause of the infinite loop in `downloadGet`: `limit` is string object.

if `limit` is string, `retry < self.limit` yield `True` in Python 2.x:

```
>>> retry = 4280
>>> limit = '3'
>>> retry < limit
True
```

Check the type of the `limit` passed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything in your `DownloadThread` code to break out of the while loop if URL is not empty.

Comment: I think thats not the problem. In the next iteration, `url` might become empty.

Answer (score 0):

You should define your loop in a more Pythonic fashion:

```
def downloadGet(self, url):
    ...
    # do not declare retry before this
    for retry in xrange(self.limit):
        ...
        try:
```

EDIT:

Alternately you could take advantage of `while` to handle your loop state more clearly than trying to `break` (although I feel like my first example is less fragile):

```
def downloadGt(self, url):
    ...
    while retry in xrange(self.limit) or succ == False:
        ...
```

This has the benefit of being more self-documented.

Though, I would consider refactoring the loop into download instead of downloader. Something like this:

```
class DownloadThread(Thread):
    ...
    def download(self, url):
        for retry in xrange(self.downloader.limit):
            succ, flv = self.downloader.downloadGet(url)
            if succ:
                return succ


class Downloader(object):
    ...
    def downloadGet(self, url)
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        try:
            response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
            page = response.read()

        # always qualify your exception handlers 
        # or you may be masking errors you don't know about
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
            return False, None

        return True, page
```